# How do I get the height of the triangle when only given 2 angles with no base side?

Tags: trigonometry

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rGaP.png)

How do I find y in this when there is no base? I've been trying different attempts to answer this but i always get the wrong answer.

Comment: Please clarify if BD is orthogonal to AC.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. i just looked at the problem again and its not a right triangle

Comment: I'm actually trying to use law of sine and cosine to solve this. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: but is BD the height you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for right triangle $BCD$

$$y=450 \cdot\sin {(57°12')}$$

[image]

Comment: What *notation* in the sketch of the geometry leads you to the belief that BCD is a right angle?

Comment: @DJohnM isn't it? in the OP the height of the triangle is mentioned, thus I suppose that is pependicular by definition of height and then BCD is right in B

Comment: ok I've asked a clarification on this

Comment: @gimusi Never mind, you are correct. The height of a triangle _always_ forms a right angle.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah indeed it was my first assumption

Comment: @gimusi Yes, but it was less an assumption than an overlooked detail.